# Multiple Domains, multiple Store Views, redirect and cookies problem

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, redirect, cookie

I have a  website with 2 store views and different domains assigned to them through `System > Web > Unsecure/Secure > Base URL` (default one with `en` code at http://tea-and-coffee.tk/ and additional with `ru` code at http://teaandcoffeeuk.tk/).

I can switch between them with default language switcher in header and everything works fine except one thing. When I go to incognito mode in my browser and open any page at `ru` store view like http://teaandcoffeeuk.tk/tea.html, it always redirects me to an index page of default store - http://tea-and-coffee.tk/.

After I manually switch to `ru` store view through language switcher, links start working fine, so my guess is that different stores require some cookies set in my browser. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I've managed to solve it with adding the following code to `index.php` just before `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'tea-and-coffee.tk':
        $mageRunCode = 'en';
        $mageRunType = 'store';
        break;
    case 'teaandcoffeeuk.tk':
        $mageRunCode = 'ru';
        $mageRunType = 'store';
        break;
    default:
        $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
        $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
        break;
}
```

This way magento resolves required store by hostname automatically. Everything is working flawlessly so far.